# Filtering on 2 not equal wildcards. Possible?

Tags: vba, excel

is it possible to filter the working table on two criteria that are wildcards. 
I want to delete all rows from my date that have Ident number in column C not starting with 1 or 4. After filtering and deleting I want to show all data again and have no blank rows in between

Is that even possible? I was trying a lot of stuff. I am posting 2 options that I thought were most likely to work - but didnt. Any info is greatly appreciated.

```
With ActiveSheet
'FIRST TRY
.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>1*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="<>4*"

'SECOND TRY
.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "<>1*", "<>4*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

'THEN I WANT ALL ROWS THAT DONT START WITH 1 OR 6 DELETED
.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End With
```

Comment: If the column you're filtering on is numeric then I don't think you can apply wildcard criteria like that.  Best you could do is probably add a "text" version of that column and filter on that.  Your first example would work of you use xlAnd as the Operator.

Comment: Hi Tim, just tried it. Doesnt work with xlAnd either.

Comment: Named argument not found is the error. I just checked and the given column C is formatted as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Tim Williams in the comment, you can't apply a text filter to a numeric column.  I personally wouldn't use a filter for this in either case, as there's a dead simple VBA only approach:

```
Dim current As Long
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim start As String

Set sheet = ActiveSheet
With sheet
    For current = .UsedRange.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        start = Left$(.Cells(current, 3), 1)
        If start <> "1" And start <> "4" Then
            .Rows(current).Delete
        End If
    Next
End With
```

**EDIT:** If the sheet is sorted, the row deletions are a *lot* faster, because you can track the start and end of ranges that need to be deleted instead of removing potentially thousands of individual rows:

```
Dim current As Long
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim start As String
Dim bottom As Long

With sheet
    For current = .UsedRange.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        start = Left$(.Cells(current, 3), 1)
        If start <> "1" And start <> "4" And bottom = 0 Then
            bottom = current
        ElseIf (start = "1" Or start = "4") And bottom <> 0 Then
            .Range((current + 1) & ":" & bottom).Delete
            bottom = 0
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Hi Comintern. I love the simplicity of this solution but it doesnt work.
1st problem with it is that it lasts extremely long and crashes excel - potentially because it looping through every cell in column 3 checking for the rows that fulfill the conditions - and there is cca 50k of those.
2nd problem is - it deletes the first row with the headings - and I dont want that.

Comment: @drLecter - The header is easy, change `To 1` to `To 2`.  It completes in a reasonable amount of time on my machine with 100000 rows of random data if sceen updating is off.  Do you have formulas in any of the cells, or is it all data? BTW, what takes so long is not the criteria checks - that's well under a second - it's the row deletes. Can it be sorted?

Comment: Hi Comintem - It has formulas but calculating is set on manual until I delete all the stuff I want out. What you gave me gets the job done and if we cant further improve it I will mark it as answer. It still lasts long - it needs cca 2-3 mins to do deleting. 
I tried adding a sorting line like this:
    Range("C2").CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=Range("C2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess
Sorting also takes cca half a minute. 
Changing to "To 2" solved not loosing headers

Comment: With the data sorted, this does the same 100K rows in under a second.  See the edit.

Comment: Thank you Sir for schooling me and providing assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Try it as two separate filters.  I have not testing this code, but am wondering if it will maintain the first filter and add the second filter.

```
'Filter 1
    .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>1*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
'Filter 2
    .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria2:="<>4*",  Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=3, _
            Criteria1:="<>1*", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>4*"
```

Col C must be formatted as "Text" - you may have to re-enter the information to be sure (you should see the grren "number stored as text" indicator on those cells)